# Dynamically wire a record contained in another record

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have a table that contains a list of document objects, and I am implementing logic to determine whether a user can delete a document or not based on whether the user created the document. However, I am not able to get a specific document's created by field based on a single document from the list, and keep getting an error saying "$documentId is not defined". This is what I'm trying to do:

**documentTable.html**

```html
<template>
    <p align="right">
        <lightning-button label="New" onclick={createRecord}></lightning-button>
    </p><br />
    <lightning-datatable
        data={documents}
        columns={columns}
        key-field="Id"
        onrowaction={handleRowAction}
        onsave={handleSave}
        hide-checkbox-column="true"
    ></lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

**documentTable.js**

```js
import CREATED_BY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Document__c.CreatedById';
import Id from '@salesforce/user/Id';
...
@track documentId;
@wire(getRecord, {recordId: $documentId, fields: [CREATED_BY_FIELD]}) document;

handleRowAction(event) {
    const actionName = event.detail.action.name;
    const row = event.detail.row;
    this.removeRecord(row.Id);
}

isDocumentCreator(recordId) {
    this.documentId = recordId;
    if (document.CREATED_BY_FIELD === Id) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

async removeRecord(recordId) {
    if (!this.isDocumentCreator(recordId)) {
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'You lack permissions to delete this document',
                message: 'You must have created the document to delete it',
                variant: 'error'
            })
        );
    } else {
        try {
            await deleteRecord(recordId);

            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Document deleted',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );

            await this.getData();
        } catch (error) {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error deleting document',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I found the solution less than an hour after posting the question. The undefined error was happening because I didn't put $documentId between quotes in the @wire line. Then I used the getFieldValue function to get the created by field. Here's the code for future reference:

```js
import CREATED_BY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Document__c.CreatedById';
import Id from '@salesforce/user/Id';

    ...
    @wire(getRecord, {recordId: '$documentId' , fields: [CREATED_BY_FIELD]}) document;
    @track documentId;

    isDocumentCreator(recordId) {
        this.documentId = recordId;
        if (getFieldValue(this.document.data, CREATED_BY_FIELD) === Id) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    ...
```